# select where date (only date from datetime)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

how can I search for a records in the database (sql server) where date dd/mm/yyyy from date format dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss .

if the column is date it's work fine but when I make it datetime and want to see if there's records in database in specific date it's different because there's time.

so how can i search for the date only when the column is datetime.

this is what i'm using:

```
    If SQL.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        SQL.conn.Close()
    End If
    DateTime1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTime1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"

    SQL.conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select count(eid) from employees_payroll WHERE eid=" & employee_id & " and wday= '" & DateTime1.Text & "'", SQL.conn)
    count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    SQL.conn.Close()
    DateTime1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: so what the best way to achieve this ??
i'm using this code to get row count from table so if the row count > 0 
then i'll show to the user that he already add this.

Comment: what is data type of wday in table employees_payroll ?

Comment: now its Date, but i want to make it datetime, and search from date only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several solutions. Cast datetime to date this eliminates the time

```
 Select * from table where cast (column as Date) = '1 jan 2017'
```

second, use date diff function

```
 Select * from table where datediff(day, column, '1Jan2017') = 0
```

third, strip time portion using datediff and dateadd

```
 Select * from table 
 where dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, column), 0) = '1Jan2017'
```

also, compare to midnight at start and end of the day

```
 Select * from table 
 where column >= '1 Jan 2017'
    and column < '2 jan 2017'
```

Last solution is only one that allows use of index on the date column

EDIT ( to address concerns raised by Joel in comments):
    Please understand that the C# code you are using to pass this query to the Server is vulnerable to what is called "SQL Injection".  If your application is constructing this SQL from input from untrusted users, this is an invitation to disaster.  As Joe; suggests in his answer below, the C# code should be modified to use command objects with defined parameters, instead of dynamically constructed SQL.  The SQL statement itself, however can still be any of the solutions suggested above.

Comment: All of these still encourage the use of string concatenation, which is NOT a good way to put data into an sql command.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn We don't know the OP's usage context. Might be just a personal home project that isn't exposed to anyone but the OP, or simply an academic lesson for school, so hack-proof is out of scope of the question. If you're the downvoter, please reconsider not punishing Charles for not addressing that which was not asked.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn , this is personal project, and its local not on the internet or shared , but if you can show me the right way i will be glad.
thank you

Comment: There are **many** reasons not to use string concatenation. Security is only one of those, though perhaps the most important. Here, parameterized queries also have the nice property of fixing his formatting problem.

Comment: @Joel,  I am wondering what you misread. None of these have anything to do with strings, except the string literal representing the target date. What, exactly are you talking about?  Are you making a comment about my solutions to the date vs datetime issue, or to his vb.net code, (which my solutions do not address)?

Comment: '1Jan2017' is a string literal, not a date value, and the by never mentioning query parameters  the answer implies he should still include the literals via string concatenation.

Comment: Every date passed to sql server, whether directly or as the value of a parameter defined as a date, is passed as a string and converted to a date (or datetime) on the fly, depending on the type of the target variable the value is being imported into.  so yes, '1jan2016' is a string. but in your code below the value passed into `@wday` is also passed in as a string by ADO.Net. The entire constructed sql is a string, constructed by the ADO.Net engine and passed as a string to the server. If you looked at the trace you would see that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Using cn  As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("Select count(eid) from employees_payroll WHERE eid= @employee_id and wday >= @wday and wday < DATEADD(dd, 1, @wday)", cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@employee_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(employee_id)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@wday", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime1.Value

    cn.Open()
    count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
End Using
```

### Some notes about this code

In .Net, you really do want to use a whole new connection object for for most operations. It's a mistake to try to re-use the same connection object throughout your application. Really. The ADO.Net provider for SQL Server uses something called connection pooling, and you lose the benefits of that when you stick with the same object in your app. Instead of a sharing a common connection object, just share a common connection string for creating the new object when you need it. Then you can also wrap things in a `Using` block, so that this connection is properly closed as needed, even if an exception is thrown. Note that I don't have to `cn.Close()` in this sample, and that's not a mistake. The `Using` block *will* take care of this properly.

**Don't use string concatenation to put data values into an sql command statement!** There are *several* reasons for this, ranging from performance (you get execution plan re-use and better query statistics) to security (no more sql injection vulernability!) to fixing formatting issues like the one you have here. Even though this looks like private winforms app, rather than public web app, you still need to use parameterized queries for this.

When you start using `DateTime` values in the database, there is **always** a time component in your column value, and Sql Server **always** compares those values using the full date and time, no exeptions. If you don't specify a time, Sql Server uses a "0" time value, meaning midnight. So comparing two "Date"s in a `DateTime` column only works if *both sides* of the comparison have exactly the same time values. If you want to know if a DateTime value falls on a specific day, the correct way to do this is the check if it's greater than or equal to the start of the day and less than the start of the next day. If you wanted to, you *could* instead cast your `wday` column to a `Date` type for this query. I encourage you *not* to do this, as it will prevent Sql Server from using any indexes that might exist for that column.

Comment: thank you this is helpful, so the best way is using parameters always??

Comment: Yes. ALWAYS use parameters for anything included in a query that is supplied by the user, and even some things that might be supplied by your application, like date or enum values.